# Numpy dot() function equivalent

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

This question is just out of pure curiosity. Suppose I have 2 matrices `a` and `b`.

```
a=np.array([[1, 2],
            [2, 3],
            [4, 5]])

b=np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
            [2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

To find their dot product, I might use `np.dot(a,b)`. But is there any other way to do this? I am not asking for any other alias functions. But maybe another way to do this like `np.sum(a*b, axis=1)`  (I know that doesn't work, it is just an example). And what if I have a 3-D matrix? Is there any other way to compute their dot product as well (without using any functions)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use the `@` operator: `a@b`.

Comment: Furthermore `np.multiply` does *not* produces a matrix multiplication.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem I was asking for a mathematical equivalent, not another operator or function

Comment: It's easy with an added bit of broadcasting.  Think about the dimensions you need to multiply and sum

Comment: @hpaulj Could you please be a bit more specific and post your answer?

Comment: `a` is (3,2), `b` is (2,4), and you want a (3,4) with some sort of sum of the size 2 dimensions, right?  If you construct a (3,2,4) array of products, you could do the sum on axis 1.  Can you make `a` (3,2,4) or (3,2,1)?  Make `b` (3,2,4) or (1,2,4)?

Comment: @hpaulj I think that can be done by `a=a[:,:,np.newaxis]` and `b=b[np.newaxis]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [66]: a=np.array([[1, 2],
    ...:             [2, 3],
    ...:             [4, 5]])
    ...: 
    ...: b=np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
    ...:             [2, 3, 4, 5]])
    ...: 
    ...:             
In [67]: np.dot(a,b)
Out[67]: 
array([[ 5,  8, 11, 14],
       [ 8, 13, 18, 23],
       [14, 23, 32, 41]])
In [68]: a@b
Out[68]: 
array([[ 5,  8, 11, 14],
       [ 8, 13, 18, 23],
       [14, 23, 32, 41]])
In [69]: np.einsum('ij,jk',a,b)
Out[69]: 
array([[ 5,  8, 11, 14],
       [ 8, 13, 18, 23],
       [14, 23, 32, 41]])
```

Broadcasted multiply and sum:

```
In [71]: (a[:,:,None]*b[None,:,:]).sum(axis=1)
Out[71]: 
array([[ 5,  8, 11, 14],
       [ 8, 13, 18, 23],
       [14, 23, 32, 41]])
In [72]: (a[:,:,None]*b[None,:,:]).shape
Out[72]: (3, 2, 4)
```